# Solve second order linear homogeneous ODE with variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have trouble solving the following ODE:
$$y''(x)+\frac{1}{2}xy'(x)-\frac{3}{2}y=0.$$ Could someone help me with this question? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. See [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).
Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers.

Comment: is this the ODE you are asking about: $y''(x)+(1/2)x y'(x)-(3/2)y=0$

Comment: See [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolveValue%5By%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+1%2F2+x+*y%27%5Bx%5D+-+3%2F2+y%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+0,+y,+x%5D).

Comment: Yes! Sorry for the confusion of my expression...

Comment: The solution containes the hypergeometric function!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  If [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=DSolveValue%5By%27%27%5Bx%5D+%2B+1%2F2+x+*y%27%5Bx%5D+-+3%2F2+y%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+0,+y,+x%5D) is to be believed, only in the form of error function.

Comment: What form of solution are you looking for? Power series, expressions in special functions, ...?

Comment: I already know that one of the solutions is x^3+6x but don't know how to get this solution.

Comment: see this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquationSecondSolution.html

Answer (score 0):

For a given differential equation 
${y}''\left( x \right)+P\left( x \right){y}'\left( x \right)+Q\left( x \right)y\left( x \right)=0$

If a solution  ${{y}_{1}}\left( x \right)$ known, then ${{y}_{2}}\left( x \right)$  is given by

**${{y}_{2}}\left( x \right)={{y}_{1}}\left( x \right)\int{\frac{{{e}^{\int{-P\left( x \right)dx}}}}{{{y}_{1}}{{\left( x \right)}^{2}}}}dx$**

So  as you suggested ${{y}_{1}}\left( x \right)=\left( {{x}^{3}}+6x \right)$ is a solution, hence

**${{y}_{2}}\left( x \right)=\left( {{x}^{3}}+6x \right)\int{\frac{{{e}^{-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{4}}}}{{{\left( {{x}^{3}}+6x \right)}^{2}}}}dx={{\text{e}}^{-\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{4}}}\left( -\frac{x}{72\left( {{x}^{2}}+6 \right)}-\frac{1}{36x} \right)-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{48}\,erf\left( \frac{x}{2} \right)$**

Where  $erf\left( z \right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\underset{0}{\overset{z}{\mathop \int }}\,{{e}^{-{{t}^{2}}}}dt$ the error function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!